# Does $G$ contain a normal subgroup that is either a 2-group, 3-group, 5-group or of order a multiple of 15?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Suppose that a group $G$ of order $450$ has exactly two subgroups, $H$
>   and $K$, of order $225$. Show that $G$ contains a non-trivial normal
>   subgroup that is either a $2$-group, a $3$-group, a $5$-group or of order a
>   multiple of $15$.

Note that $|G|=450=2\times3^2\times5^2$. *Sylow I* thus gives that $G$ contains a Sylow $2$-subgroup, $3$-subgroup, and $5$-subgroup. This is where I get stuck. I am fairly certain I want to consider $H \cap K$ and proceed on a case-by-case basis, eliminating each of the above options.

What's the best way to go about finding the non-trivial subgroup in $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$I don't quite get it. $H$ and $K$ are normal, as they have index $2$. So what is the subgroup $H K$? Its order is 
$$
\Size{H K} = \frac{\Size{H} \Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}}
= \Size{H} \cdot \frac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}}.
$$
Since $H K$ is a subgroup, this number divides the order of $G$, so that
$$
\Size{H} \cdot \frac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}} \text{ divides } \Size{G},
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}} \text{ divides } \frac{\Size{G}}{\Size{H}} = 2.
$$
But also
$$
\frac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}} \text{ divides } \Size{K} = 225.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}} = 1,
$$
and thus $K = H \cap K$, that is, $K \le H$, and thus $H = K$, as $H$ and $K$ have the same order.

So such a group does not exist.

---

As noted in a comment, this is a particular case of a more general result that tells you that if $H$ is a *normal* subgroup of $G$, and $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that  $\gcd(\Size{K}, \Size{G : H}) = 1$, then $K \le H$. (The proof is really the same as above, where you get that $\dfrac{\Size{K}}{\Size{H \cap K}}$ divides both $\Size{K}$ and $\Size{G : H}$, and thus must be $1$.) In particular, if  $\gcd(\Size{H}, \Size{G : H}) = 1$, then $H$ is the unique subgroup of $G$ of its order.

Comment: The question as stated is correct but there might be an error in my attempted proof, if that's what you're saying.

Comment: It is late, so I may be mistaken. But if you have a normal subgroup of order coprime to index, then this is unique. So there cannot be **two** subgroups of order $225$.

Comment: I think it is obvious that there is a mistake. A subgroup of index $2$ is normal. So $H$ is a normal subgroup of order a multiple of $15$. (I still claim that there cannot possibly be **two distinct** subgroups $H, K$.)

Comment: I may be mistaken but you might be thinking of: $H$ is unique if $gcd(|H|, |G|)=1$, not if $gcd(|H|, 2)=1$

Comment: $\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$How can a non-trivial subgroup $H$ have order coprime to the order of the group $G$ it is contained in? You always have $\gcd(\Size{H}, \Size{G}) = \Size{H}$, by Lagrange's theorem.  I claim that if $H$ is normal, and $\gcd(\Size{H}, \Size{G:H}) = 1$, then $H$ is unique of its order.

Comment: Hm. I really am not sure. This problem came straight from my textbook so I doubt there is a mistake but I suppose it's possible. Can you perhaps just assume $H$ and $K$ can be distinct, for the time being? I will check in with my professor tomorrow.

Comment: $\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$Ok, let us assume $H, K$ distinct, So $H K > H$. Since $H K$ is a subgroup, from $2 = \Size{G : H} = \Size{G : H K} \Size{H K: H}$, we obtain $H K = G$. By the formula above, $2 = \Size{G : H} = \Size{H K : H} = \Size{K : H \cap K}$. So $2$ divides $\Size{K} = 225$. Ouch!

Comment: Indeed, it is well known that a group of order twice odd has a unique subgroup of index 2. (Indeed, any group with a cyclic Sylow 2-subgroup has a normal 2-complement, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_p-complement). So, as Andreas says, the group $G$ in the question does not exist, and so we can prove anything we want about it...

Comment: Andreas is totally right. From which textbook originates this problem?